# MongoDB - InsertOne() get InsertID

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am inserting a doc into a collection called users. After the insert, I want to return the doc id in order to keep working with it. So I wrote this code:

```
this.db.collection("users")
  .insertOne({ xy })
   .then(ref => {
      console.log(ref.insertedId);
   });
```

The returned insertedId equals to something like this:

```
id:Uint8Array(12) [89, 131, 152, 99, 28, 157, 43, 0, 0, 90, 228, 11]
```

But I can't really work with this. I need a continous string or number.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Use MongooseJS : https://mongoosejs.com/

Create a **User Model** inside `models/user.js`

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var userSchema = new Schema({
    name:  String,
    email: String,
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  },{
    collection: 'User'
  });

var User = module.exports  = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

require this `user.js` file in your `index.js`

```
global.User = require('./models/user');
```

your index.js should be :

```
global.express = require('express');
global.app = express();
global.bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
global.mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
global._=require('underscore');
global.User = require('./models/user');

app.post('/insert',function(req,res){
     console.log(req.body);

     var user=new User({
        name:req.body.name;
        email:req.body.email;
     });
     user.save();
     User.find({},function(err,users){
        (!err && users){
           console.log(users);
           var userIDs=_.pluck(users,'_id');
            return res.json({
                users:userIDs
            });
        }
     })
}); 

app.listen(3000);
```

your frontend side should be html form

```
<form method="post" action="/insert">
   <input type="text" name="name" required/>
   <input type="email" name="email" required/>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey! I am currently using MongoDB's Stitch Service and since my whole application already builds on that, I do not want to redo every db realted function. Is there no way to do it with my setup? I mean its such a basic feature and I am getting an id, just none which I can work with.